# codeigniter - Flashdata not clearing

Tags: codeigniter, session, model-view-controller

i'm new with codeigniter and use flashdata to display message from controller to view. However, flashdata is not cleared automatically after i refresh the view or move to the other pages and back it still remain. Please help.

Here is my code in controller:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('_flash_message', 'Thanks for your subscription.');
    redirect(site_url('cp/subscribe'), 'refresh');
```

In view:

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('_flash_message'); ?>
```

I used XAMPP for localhost, already turn off cache mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try

On Controller

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'Thanks for your subscription.');

redirect(base_url('cp/subscribe'));
```

On View

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('flash_message') {
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('flash_message');?>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view you need to add an if statement to check if the flashdata is set.  When refreshing the browser it will not be set so the message will not reappear.

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('_flash_message')) : ?> 
   <?php echo '<p>' .$this->session->flashdata('_flash_message'). '</p>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```